# VB.Net DateTime conversion

Tags: jquery, vb.net, datetime

I have a jquery datepicker in a usercontrol.
On the usercontrol i have a property that will return the selected date to the page which contains my usercontrol.

I try to convert the string to a date:

```
Dim MyDate As System.DateTime = System.Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDateF.Value, System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

i keep getting the error:

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

The date which is in de txtFromDateF => 23-06-2015

I thought that the "InvariantInfo" would make sure that I always get the date in the correct format, no matter what my language-setting is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`
doesn't contain format pattern `dd-MM-yyyy`(26-06-2015)

From MSDN about InvariantCulture

> The InvariantCulture property can be used to persist data in a
>   culture-independent format.   This provides a **known format that does
>   not change**

For using invariant format in converting `string` to `DateTime` your string value must be formatted with one of invariant culture format patterns.

Use `Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns()`
for checking/printing all patterns

For custom formatted strings you can use [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
Dim datevalue As Stirng = "23-06-2015"
Dim customFormat As String = "dd-MM-yyyy"
Dim yourdate As DateTime
If DateTime.TryParseExact(datevalue, 
                          customFormat,
                          Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
                          yourdate) = True Then
    'Use parsed DateTime value
Else
    'Notice about wrong formatted date
End If
```